# C++ <function-style-cast> error while implicitely asking for several conversions calling multiple constructors at once with templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

So it seems like C++ doesn't like it when it has to deal with several **conversions** at once (or more probably I don't know how to do it).
Here are my **constructors** (each T are different templates, one per class):

```
Number();
Number(long long int x);

Fraction(T num = T(0), T denom = T(1)) : m_num(num), m_denom(denom) { format(); }

Polynom(T x = T(0)) : m_size(1) { m_vect.push_back(T(x)); }

Matrix(int const& m, int const& n = 0, T const& x = T(0)) : m_m(m), m_n(n) { /*blablabla*/ }
```

And I am aksing for that :

```
Matrix<Polynom<Fraction<Number> > > M(5, 5);
```

I expected that it could be converted step by step as I have written T(...) everywhere, but it doesn't. How to solve that problem?

**EDIT:**

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
Matrix(int const& m, int const& n = 0, T const& x = T(0)) : m_m(m), m_n(n) {
    if (m_n == 0)
        m_n = m_m;
    T X(0);
    m_grid = new T*[m_m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_m; i++) {
        m_grid[i] = new T[m_n];
        for (int j = 0; j < m_n; j++) {
            X = new T(x);
            m_grid[i][j] = X;
        }
    }
}
/* ... */
private:
 T** m_grid;
 int m_m, m_n;
}

template <typename T>
class Polynom {
 public:
 //Polynom() : m_size(0) {}
 Polynom(T x = T(0)) : m_size(1) { m_vect.push_back(T(x)); }
 /* ... */
 private:
  std::vector<T> m_vect;
  int m_size;
}

template <typename T>
class Fraction {
 public:
 Fraction(T num = T(0), T denom = T(1)) : m_num(num), m_denom(denom) { format(); }
 /* ... */
private:
 T m_num;
 T m_denom;
}

class Number {
public:
 Number(long long int x){
 if(x == 0)
     m_digits.push_back(0);
 while (x != 0) {
     m_digits.push_back(x % 10);
     x /= 10;
 }
 m_neg = (x < 0);
 /* ... */
private:
 std::vector<int> m_digits;
 bool m_neg;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give us an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited, is it enough?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `Matrix` constructor that can take the types (it could be that all it does is forwarding those arguments, but it has to take them).

```
template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
  template<typename ... Args>
  Matrix(Args && ... args)
  : mem(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  { }

  T mem;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I really get it, does this implies that I have to use Matrix<Polynom, Fraction, Number>, or something like that? I also haven't really understood your syntax. Maybe my edit can help.